# Getting an Error on visual studio code

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I am getting the below error on visual studio code

> The salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home setting defined in VS Code
>   settings points to a missing folder. For information on how to setup
>   the Salesforce Apex extension, see Set Your Java Version.

my setting in vs code is

`"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1"`

and this path is correct in my local file system.

Comment: did you try restarting VS code?

Comment: 100 times and even restarted my machine several times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce Extension for VS Code unfortunately doesn't seem to work with Java versions greater than 8 and that your Java version seems to be 12.

You will need to ensure that you have a Java 8 installed in your local system. I had faced the same issue and was able to resolve it only using Java 8 version. Here's the issue details related to this topic: [salesforcedx-vscode-apex does not accept versions of Java greater than 8](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/930).

Additional note here: You don't need the JDK here, just having a Java 8 JRE works as well. In my current workspace, I just have Java 8 JRE version set in `salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home` and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I am trying to install Java 8, will post if this will work

Comment: I have uninstalled the java 12 and installed the java 8 changed the path accordingly but the error is still the same

Comment: @gs650x Just make sure that your new installation is included in the PATH variable too and that you have restarted your VS Code to reflect that.

Comment: in environment variable I have %JAVA_HOME%\bin; and in JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin

Comment: Could you please confirm if this is correct, I have wasted hours on setting this :(

Comment: @gs650x You don't need to specify \bin. Refer to [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html). And that your `apex.java.home` should point to the JDK installation folder.

Comment: In environment variable, I have mentioned bin in vs code I have not added bin

Comment: @gs650x I could confirm that this works. You may like to review the path settings both in your env. variable and vs code. If it points to an installation of Java 8, it will work.

Comment: But it is not working :(

Comment: You can find this [documented here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode). Also make sure that your VS Code version is v1.26 and later.

Comment: My VS code is 1.33

Comment: As of May 2019 java 11 is supported along with 8

Comment: @RickSchmidt That's good to know. The last time I had tried it didn't work except for Java 8.x. I still feel there should not be a hardcoded version requirement for a tool like this.